# Laravel Logic with Price Tiers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I wonder if somebody can point me in the right direction.

I've got a e-commerce platform built on Laravel, works a treat! However I now want to introduce price tiers for certain products.

For example, I have one item priced at £10.00.

I want to introduce multiple pricing tiers for this item

- Order between 1 & 10 = Unit price is £10.00
- Order between 11 & 15 = Unit price is £8.00
- Order more than 16+ = Unit price is £6.00

I had it in my mind that I would create two additional tables to my product tables called tiers.

1 being Product_tiers containing

- product_id
- tier_id

Another table Tiers

- id
- Tier Name
- percentage_drop
- less_than_quantity

My question is in a controller when persisting an order to the platform how I would workout the quantity entered to order is within one of the tiers above?

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can research? Google didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relations are correct, the only problem lies with `less_than_quantity` field. Prefer `min_quantity` and `max_quantity` to make suitable tier search easier.

So, your final tables are

```
product
 - id
 - name
 - price
 - blah blah...

tier
 - id
 - name
 - percentage_drop
 - min_quantity
 - max_quantity

product_tier
  - id
  - product_id
  - tier_id
```

You can then use it this way

```
public function getProductTier($productId)
{
  $quantity = request()->get('quantity');

  $product = Product::find($id);
  $tiers = $product->tiers;

  $tier = $tiers->filter(function($tier) use ($quantity) {
    $quantity >= $tier->min_quantity && $quantity < $max_quantity;
  })->first();

  $final_rate = ($product->price - (($tier->drop_percentage/100) * $product->price));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, nice tip on the max and min quantity! And the function for filtering the tiers looks like it could do the job.. I'll research a little more then mark this answer.. thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Dev.Wol Let me know if you face any issue. Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: I've tried the above but unfortunately it filters out all my tiers resulting in an object not found when trying to get the final rate.. I've dd() the $product->tiers and I can see the three tiers and the quantity I'm passing to the filter is 1.

Comment: Fixed! all I had to do after reading the laravel docs is add the return within the function.

Comment: @Dev.Wol Return? Where? The code I gave was obviously a dummy code. You'll have to make changes to according to your needs. I hoped my answer helped you :)

Comment: I had to add the return within the $tiers->filter function.